# Attempting to remove extra "edges" from truncated icosahedron lead to excessively global concequences

Tags: blender, mesh

I need a truncated icosahedron.  Blender lets me do that with add -> mesh -> math function -> regular solid (assuming the extra plugin is installed.) So far so good.  However, the mesh that is created does not use ngons.  This means that each hexagon or pentagon face is cut by an unusable edge approximately through the middle.  These extra "lines" destroy the visual symmetry I need for the wireframe.

I have tried deleting the extra edges. This results in the in the removal of far more than just the offending edge.  It blows a huge hole in the whole object. I have tried merging the two faces (which compose the pentagon or hexagon) into an ngon. Somehow this again ends up doing far more than just merge the two parts of the face.

No matter what I try I get unintended effects that are far to global. I have also considered drawing fresh lines over only the desired edges. I cannot figure out how to do this either. I have also extracted the faces and edges with python, but those are too cumbersome to edit... and then what?

How do I get a nice clean geometric wire Frame without distracting extra edges?

Comment: This looks like a question for the Blender StackExchange. Meshes in games are almost always triangle meshes, since that's what GPUs consume most readily.

Comment: Thanks.  I have reposted it on the Blender StackExchange

Comment: Please delete the copy here then, so that your question doesn't get closed as a cross-post. You should post each question on just one site in the StackExchange network, to keep all the best answers in one place and avoid leaving dead ends for future searchers.